# Diagrama de relacionamento condicional entre classes

Tags: classes, modelagem, relacionamento, uml

Fiz um diagrama e modelei a classe Parceiros para envolver clientes, fornecedores, prestadores de serviço, etc., que herdará atributos das classes abstratas `Pessoa->Física` ou `Pessoa->Jurídica`. Porém não tenho certeza que está correto, se uma classe pode escolher se relacionar com duas outras diretamente sem alguma espécie de condição já que não se relacionará com duas ao mesmo tempo. Poderiam por gentileza avaliar de modo geral e me dizerem se está incorreto, o que preciso corrigir?

[image: Diagrama de classes:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem problema algum relacionar-se com mais de uma tabela ao mesmo tempo, embora neste caso nem é ao mesmo tempo, por ser condicional ou se relaciona com uma ou com a outra.

Estrutura de dados não é algoritmo, então o condicional é só no conceito, não existe nada que indique isto.

Não posso afirmar se está tudo correto porque não sei os requisitos e são eles que mandam no que é certo ou errado. Exceto pelo [`salario` ser `float` que certamente está errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Eu só discordo de `Colaborador` ser derivado de `Fisica`, embora isto seja quase caso perdido, quase todo mundo acha assim, até porque os exemplos, errados, de orientação a objetos são sempre mostrados assim. A colaboração é só um papel que uma pessoa exerce no modelo, não é uma relação de **é um** para ser herança. Por sinal quase todas as vezes que se herda de uma classe concreta está errado, pelo menos em modelagem de domínio. Não que isso seja uma regra de ouro divulgada por todos, mas é minha percepção depois de 30 anos fazendo isto. Raros casos que vi isso funcionar e mesmo assim sempre era possível herdar de abstrações no lugar de herdar do concreto.

Não analisei todos os aspectos do modelo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entendi... então achei que necessitasse algum tipo diferente de relacionamento como alguma estrutura de decisão...

Vou editar também o tipo de salário para Decimal

Confesso que fiquei confuso com sua observação quanto a classe colaborador, vou buscar entender melhor sobre esse assunto...

No demais, agradeço muito!!!

Comment: Aqui no site tem várias informações sobre isso. Mas se você não entendeu está usando mecanismo que não entende, portanto o correto realmente é se informar mais sobre ele ante de usá-lo, aí tome a decisão que quiser, mas porque quer aquilo não porque não entende aquilo.